# retrieve data from multiple table using ajax

Tags: ajax, database, laravel, relational

**this is posts table:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('prf_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('prf_id')->references('id')->on('profiles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->longText('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('posts');
    }
}
```

**this is comments table:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('prf_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('prf_id')->references('id')->on('profiles')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->longText('comment');
            $table->integer('like')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('comments');
    }
}
```

**this post model**

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Post extends Model
    {
        protected $table='posts';
        protected $fillable = ['status'];
    protected $hidden = [];

    public function profile(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile', 'prf_id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function comment(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }


}
```

**this is Comment model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table='comments';
    protected $fillable = ['comment','like'];


    protected $hidden = [];

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'post_id');
    }

    public function profile(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile', 'prf_id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

In blade page i can easilly retrieve all comments of a particular post like :
suppose i got $posts as post

```
@foreach ($post->comment as $comment)
{{$comment->comment}}
```

but in ajax how could i do this 
suppose i **return response()->json($posts);**
any suggestion ?it will help me a lot

Comment: include your javascript code

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write `response()->json($posts)`, You can simply `return $posts` and Laravel will convert response to JSON automatically.

About Your exact problem: When querying `$posts` in controller, add `with('comment')` execution, like: `$posts = Post::with('comment')->get()` it will then return posts with comment prefetched.
It's Laravel's **eager loading**, You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: i want to do this using ajax thats why i write response()->json($posts) this